When using PrimeVue with TailwindCSS, some components show up as raw HTML and are not styled
I've been trying to get PrimeVue set up with my TailwindCSS project for a while. However, I keep running into this issue where, when I add a component, there is 0 styling on it.  and it looks like that (this is supposed to be a toggleSwitch). I followed the PrimeVue setup and the Tailwind-PrimeUI setups but it is still not working. PLEASE HELP

Just adding on, the elements DO WORK and are completely functional but the styling is not there, and that happens with every single component. Maybe it is an issue with how I set it up with both prime vue and tailwind prime ui but I'm not sure how I could get help for that here without just sending all of my code.

Turns out I just set it up wrong somehow, I removed all of the plugins and such and redid it and it worked. One cause might be that I did app.component() after doing app.use(PrimeVue)?
